# Copying code snippets from Visual Studio 2012

Tags: colors, visual-studio-2012, powerpoint, copy-paste

I want to create some documentation for my code in Word or PowerPoint. I simply copy a block of code (Ctrl+C) and then paste it in Word or PowerPoint. When I paste, I can choose to keep the original formatting so as to get the original code coloring.

Now, my problem is that if I paste into an area that has a colored background, the text will keep the Visual Studio background color (white or dark gray depending on the theme).

Is there a way I can set a transparent background color for the text so that I'll see the area's background color?

I tried with or without the HTML Copy option from the Productivity Power Tools add-in.

It worked well in previous VS versions.

Answer (score 3):

You're close with the HTML Copy feature.  Perhaps change the BeforeCodeSnippet to:

Note I've dropped the {background} tag so it shouldn't even be part of the markup.

You may find [some additional information here](http://codinglifestyle.wordpress.com/2013/05/17/copy-and-paste-formatting-with-visual-studios-dark-theme/)